# Not able to get response_body from response hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a call and in response I am getting like this:

```
   http_response = make_request
   => #<Faraday::Response:0x00007fa2adf6b010
   @env=
   #<struct Faraday::Env
     method=:post,
     request_body=
     "{\”abc\":\”abc\",\”xyz\":\”xyz\"}",
     url=#<URI::HTTPS https://localhost:3000/user/data>,
     request=
      #<struct Faraday::RequestOptions
      params_encoder=nil,
      proxy=nil>,
      request_headers={"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Accept"=>"application/json", "User-Agent"=>”Grab"},

      response=#<Faraday::Response:0x00007fa2adf6b010 ...>,

      status=200,
      reason_phrase="OK",
      response_body=
        "{\”abc\":\”abc\",\”xyz\":\”xyz\"}">,
     @on_complete_callbacks=[]>
```

I want to fetch response_body from http_response. How can I get it and how can I compare this with actual object in rails rspec.

In rspecs:

```
      expect(response).to eq true
```

Comment: please try below answer @kumar-nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried below to parse response

```
JSON.parse(http_response.body)
```

Comment: Menon. If in a response "{\”abc\":\”1\",\”xyz\":\”2\"}"
response["abc"]  givig me abc value not 1.

Comment: If it would be like this:  e_response = { "abc": "1", "xyz": "2"}, then e_response[:abc] gives 1.